# utPLSQL Installation: prompts

Tags: plsql, installation, tdd

Trying to install utPLSQL I receive a lot of strange prompts, asking me for stuff such as next_script, txt_message, min_ or major_version. I can't find any coments on this in the internet and followed the guide from http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/Doc/fourstep.html. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you run the install scripts as stated?  Worked for me.  Please show the prompts you are getting.

Comment: The utPLSQL install has always been pretty bullet-proof for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: What Oracle versions are the database and client? Are you using SQLPLUS? Have you made any changes to the system variables (i.e. using the SET command from SQLPLUS)? Can you provide the exact output?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help. I'm really new to the whole oracle world and did not run it in SQLPLUS since I had trouble connecting and heard it wouldn't be neccessary. So simply running the whole thing in SQLPLUS solved it.